# How to check if javascript array holds property with specific value, if so returns true

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a select - option in angular, and I need to check values that have same id as id in database, so I have tried something like this:

```
isDropdownValueSelected(amf: ApplicationModuleForm): boolean {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.role.applicationForms.length; i++) {
      if (this.role.applicationForms[i].id == amf.id) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
 }
```

My angular part:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
     <select id="applicationModuleFormSelect" name="applicationModuleFormSelect" class="form-control multiselect-select-all" multiple="multiple" data-fouc>
        <option *ngFor="let amf of appModuleForms;" [value]="amf.id" [selected]="isDropdownValueSelected(amf)">{{amf.title}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

So basically there I wanted to loop for each id in option and if I found similar in my array I would return true, because array `this.role.applicationForms` holds values from database, but unfortunatelly this does not works, nothing is selected in dropdown and I tested with console log it says only 1 value exist even if there are 3..

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to move the false value to the end for returning, because every `return` statement ends the function.

```
isDropdownValueSelected(amf: ApplicationModuleForm): boolean {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.role.applicationForms.length; i++) {
        if (this.role.applicationForms[i].id == amf.id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function only works when the id of the first element is matched, because you're returning the value on every check.

You should update the code to be like this:

```
isDropdownValueSelected(amf: ApplicationModuleForm): boolean {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.role.applicationForms.length; i++) {
        if (this.role.applicationForms[i].id == amf.id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `applicationForms` is an array, you can use the method [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
isDropdownValueSelected(amf: ApplicationModuleForm): boolean {
  return this.role.applicationForms.some(({id}) => id === amf.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `some` operator instead of looping on your elements:

```
isDropdownValueSelected(amf: ApplicationModuleForm): boolean {
    return this.role.applicationForms.some(e => e.id === amf.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `for` loop:

```
isDropdownValueSelected(amf: ApplicationModuleForm): boolean {
            if (this.role.applicationForms.find(x => x.id == amf.id)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```